# Azure Data Factory - Read in a list of filepaths from a fileshare and save to Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

What I have is a list of filepaths, saved inside a text file.

eg: filepaths.txt ==

C:\Docs\test1.txt

C:\Docs\test2.txt

C:\Docs\test3.txt

How can I set up a Azure Data Factory pipeline, to essentially loop through each file path and copy it to Azure Blob Storage? So in blob storage, I would have:

- \Docs\test1.txt
- \Docs\test2.txt
- \Docs\test3.txt

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "List of files" option in the copy activity. But to do this in 1 step, your txt file with the list of files needs to be in the same Source as where the actual files are present.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anupam. Is it possible to use a lookup to get the txt file list values and then pass that as input to the 'Path to file list' field?

Comment: Not in 1 activity but you can  pass each file value into a for loop containing 1 copy activity and copy the files one at a time in a for loop