# Azure Data Factory - Copy list of files to flat directory and preserve filename

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This is sort of following on from this question asked:
[Azure Data Factory - Read in a list of filepaths from a fileshare and save to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476530/azure-data-factory-read-in-a-list-of-filepaths-from-a-fileshare-and-save-to-bl)

What I have is essentially a list of filepaths saved inside a text file, as below:
eg: filepaths.txt ==

- C:\Docs\subfolder1\test1.txt
- C:\Docs\subfolder2\test2.txt
- C:\Docs\subfolder3\test3.txt

The files I want to copy can be in different subfolders. I want to copy all these files to Blob, so that the output in Blob looks like below:

- /CombinedSubfolder/test1.txt
- /CombinedSubfolder/test2.txt
- /CombinedSubfolder/test3.txt

Where all my files from the original fileshare are in the same subfolder (Regardless of what subfolder they were in before) AND they keep their original filename.
I've been trying to mess with lookups and for each loops but I can't seem to figure out the best approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

- Step1:  Use `Lookup Activity` to read data from your text file where you
  have file paths saved.

> The lookup activity in the Azure Data Factory pipeline is most commonly used for
> configuration lookup. It contains the original dataset. Lookup
> activity was used to extract data from a source dataset and save it as
> the activity's output. The output of the search activity is often
> utilised later in the pipeline to make a choice and configure the
> system accordingly.

Using : `@activity(‘activityName‘).output`

- Step2:  Use `ForEach Activity` to iterate over each file path.

> In your pipeline, the ForEach activity establishes a recurring control
> flow. This activity might be used to loop through a list of things and
> perform defined tasks.

- Step3:  Use `Copy Activity` and have dynamic datasets in source and
  sink. Make datasets points to dynamically to your desired
  location.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the flow i followed using data flow

Mysource:
/Input1/file1.txt
/Input2/file2.txt
and i want to move to a folder called DesiredOutputFolder

Lookup activity gets the source file paths

Then use a foreach loop to loop thru

Inside foreach, i had a data flow and under source settings, i had pointed to source file using a data flow parameter

[image: source]

[image: dataflowparam]

in a derived column, im using this expression to get just the filename

replace(replace(filaname,'/Input/','/DesiredOutputFolder/'),'/Output/','/DesiredOutputFolder/')

under Sink Setting tab,

[image: sink]

once i run, i will have the files moved to a single folder

My Input container looks like
[image: InputFolder]
My Output folder looks like
[image: Aftercopy]